# selecting a file in python to attach to a whatsapp web chat with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I want to use python and selenium to send some text and images to a group of my contacts. I already have a working code for sending the text, but have failed to find a way to send the images. I'm particularly stuck at selecting the image.

My code is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import time
import pyautogui

service = Service(log_path = "log.log")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = service)

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

print("Scan QR Code, And then Enter")
input()
print("Logged In")

contacts = ["John Doe", "Mary Jane"]

text = """This text works"""

file_path = "/home/xyz/Downloads/abcdef.jpeg"

for contact in contacts:

    input_box_search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]")

    input_box_search.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    for i in contact:
        input_box_search.send_keys(i)
        time.sleep(0.05)

    selected_contact = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@title='"+contact+"']")
    selected_contact.click()

    inp_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]"
    input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, inp_xpath)
    time.sleep(2)

    input_box.click()

    for i in text:
        input_box.send_keys(i)
        time.sleep(0.05)

    input_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(2)

    add_sign = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div")
    add_sign.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    photo_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/span/div/ul/div/div[2]/li/div/span")
    photo_icon.click()

    ### This one fails. So does keyboard
    pyautogui.typewrite(file_path)

    send_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/span/div/span/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div")
    send_icon.click()

driver.quit()
```

I am able to click the plus sign, select the "photos and videos" item in the menu, but then a file selector window is open and I haven't been able to select the file I want. I'm working in an ubuntu machine, and if I just Ctrl-v the path to the file after the window pops-up, the pasted text is taken as search, the file is selected, and just an additional ENTER is taken as selecting the file (closing the window and leaving the code ready to click the send button `send_icon`.

My problem is I can't find how to send the file path to that specific window, so I can't select the file to send it.[image: This is the window in which I can't select the file]

I'm open to a different approach (I've been working on this for some hours now), as long as it doesn't involve the whatsapp API (I want to use selenium for this specific task).

#### What I've Tried

I went through the following SO questions that seem to be related: [using puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538449/how-to-send-file-attachment-to-whatsapp-web-using-puppeteer), [usign javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264185/how-to-send-image-media-messages-on-whatsapp-web?rq=2), [using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167870/how-to-send-a-file-to-specific-contact-in-whatsapp-using-url-launcher-flutter?rq=2). All answers involve using the API, so none of them work in my case.

I also tried to use `pyautogui.typewrite(file_path)` and `keyboard.press_and_release(file_path)`, but they send the key presses to the window from which I'm running the script (the terminal or emacs), and not to the one opened by the browser.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472542/2681662

Comment: it totally does @MSH! If you want to submit an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as such.